# How to check if an element is having an attribute using selenium-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here is the web code

```html
<div data-module="OKVideo" data-options="{&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;VideoPopup_player_1727943084608&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:&quot;491&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;275&quot;,&quot;notifyEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-10-15/vp.swf&quot;,&quot;url11&quot;:&quot;https://st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-10-15/vp11.swf&quot;,&quot;html5url&quot;:&quot;//st.mycdn.me/static/MegaPlayer/10-11-50/okHtml5Player.min&quot;,&quot;minFlashVersionNewPlayer&quot;:&quot;11.2&quot;,&quot;wmode&quot;:&quot;opaque&quot;,&quot;asa&quot;:true,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;UPLOADED_ODKL&quot;,&quot;flashvars&quot;:{&quot;referer&quot;:&quot;https://www.shahidpro.tv/&quot;,&quot;relatedAlways&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;metadata&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;provider\&quot;:\&quot;UPLOADED_ODKL\&quot;,\&quot;service\&quot;:\&quot;ok\&quot;,\&quot;owner\&quot;:false,\&quot;voted\&quot;:false,\&quot;likeCount\&quot;:0,\&quot;subscribed\&quot;:false,\&quot;isWatchLater\&quot;:false,\&quot;slot\&quot;:0,\&quot;siteZone\&quot;:-1,\&quot;showAd\&quot;:false,\&quot;fromTime\&quot;:0,\&quot;author\&quot;:{\&quot;id\&quot;:\&quot;565690732096\&quot;,\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;SAMR ZAN\&quot;,\&quot;profile\&quot;:\&quot;/profile/565690732096\&quot;},\&quot;movie\&quot;:{\&quot;id\&quot;:\&quot;1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;movieId\&quot;:\&quot;1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;likeId\&quot;:\&quot;1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;contentId\&quot;:\&quot;834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;poster\&quot;:\&quot;https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=AEF0PjOBfKSCKs0AX-NHBglGBtoSnlj-w7r7-4MFAFw9g4biXbYyD2f2E83LOe0CGcT12ru7KHrHmBnSbxBCDBLP\\u0026fn=external_8\&quot;,\&quot;duration\&quot;:\&quot;1294\&quot;,\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;ikyn-133ar\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://www.ok.ru/video/1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;link\&quot;:\&quot;/video/1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;collageInfo\&quot;:{\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=AEE-HZfz734vGAKlsp5gLh-p5dsMcpUmst4efNIIuw5-O4biXbYyD2f2E83LOe0CGcTKJLHsazBXODze0CkTvfuB\&quot;,\&quot;frequency\&quot;:10,\&quot;height\&quot;:44,\&quot;width\&quot;:80,\&quot;count\&quot;:130},\&quot;status\&quot;:\&quot;OK\&quot;,\&quot;statusText\&quot;:\&quot;OK\&quot;,\&quot;isLive\&quot;:false,\&quot;notPublished\&quot;:false},\&quot;admanMetadata\&quot;:{},\&quot;partnerId\&quot;:0,\&quot;ownerMovieId\&quot;:\&quot;1727943084608\&quot;,\&quot;alwaysShowRec\&quot;:false,\&quot;videos\&quot;:[{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;mobile\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=4\\u0026sig=LW6aS8WtlvM\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;seekSchema\&quot;:3,\&quot;disallowed\&quot;:false},{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;lowest\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=0\\u0026sig=npEpKHETvNw\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;seekSchema\&quot;:3,\&quot;disallowed\&quot;:false},{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;low\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=1\\u0026sig=sZsahX1_3M4\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;seekSchema\&quot;:3,\&quot;disallowed\&quot;:false},{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;sd\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=2\\u0026sig=MyZn0feEv34\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;seekSchema\&quot;:3,\&quot;disallowed\&quot;:false},{\&quot;name\&quot;:\&quot;hd\&quot;,\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=3\\u0026sig=F8Z1zwkFbnY\\u0026ct=0\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;seekSchema\&quot;:3,\&quot;disallowed\&quot;:false}],\&quot;metadataEmbedded\&quot;:\&quot;\\u003C?xml version=\\\&quot;1.0\\\&quot; encoding=\\\&quot;UTF-8\\\&quot;?\\u003E\\u003CMPD xmlns:xsi=\\\&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\&quot; xmlns=\\\&quot;urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011\\\&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=\\\&quot;urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011\\\&quot; type=\\\&quot;static\\\&quot; mediaPresentationDuration=\\\&quot;PT1294.97S\\\&quot; minBufferTime=\\\&quot;PT0.5S\\\&quot; profiles=\\\&quot;urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CPeriod id=\\\&quot;0\\\&quot; start=\\\&quot;PT0S\\\&quot; duration=\\\&quot;PT1294.97S\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CAdaptationSet id=\\\&quot;0\\\&quot; segmentAlignment=\\\&quot;true\\\&quot; subsegmentAlignment=\\\&quot;true\\\&quot; subsegmentStartsWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\&quot;0\\\&quot; bandwidth=\\\&quot;122768\\\&quot; width=\\\&quot;256\\\&quot; height=\\\&quot;144\\\&quot; quality=\\\&quot;mobile\\\&quot; frameRate=\\\&quot;30\\\&quot; codecs=\\\&quot;avc1.64000C,mp4a.40.2\\\&quot; audioSamplingRate=\\\&quot;44100\\\&quot; mimeType=\\\&quot;video/mp4\\\&quot; startWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026amp;srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026amp;srcAg=CHROME\\u0026amp;ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026amp;type=4\\u0026amp;sig=LW6aS8WtlvM\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=834622982720\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\&quot;1342-2417\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\&quot;0-1341\\\&quot;/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot; bandwidth=\\\&quot;359152\\\&quot; width=\\\&quot;426\\\&quot; height=\\\&quot;240\\\&quot; quality=\\\&quot;lowest\\\&quot; frameRate=\\\&quot;30\\\&quot; codecs=\\\&quot;avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2\\\&quot; audioSamplingRate=\\\&quot;44100\\\&quot; mimeType=\\\&quot;video/mp4\\\&quot; startWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026amp;srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026amp;srcAg=CHROME\\u0026amp;ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026amp;type=0\\u0026amp;sig=npEpKHETvNw\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=834622982720\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\&quot;1343-2418\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\&quot;0-1342\\\&quot;/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\&quot;2\\\&quot; bandwidth=\\\&quot;765536\\\&quot; width=\\\&quot;640\\\&quot; height=\\\&quot;360\\\&quot; quality=\\\&quot;low\\\&quot; frameRate=\\\&quot;30\\\&quot; codecs=\\\&quot;avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2\\\&quot; audioSamplingRate=\\\&quot;44100\\\&quot; mimeType=\\\&quot;video/mp4\\\&quot; startWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026amp;srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026amp;srcAg=CHROME\\u0026amp;ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026amp;type=1\\u0026amp;sig=sZsahX1_3M4\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=834622982720\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\&quot;1344-2419\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\&quot;0-1343\\\&quot;/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\&quot;3\\\&quot; bandwidth=\\\&quot;1361072\\\&quot; width=\\\&quot;852\\\&quot; height=\\\&quot;480\\\&quot; quality=\\\&quot;sd\\\&quot; frameRate=\\\&quot;30\\\&quot; codecs=\\\&quot;avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2\\\&quot; audioSamplingRate=\\\&quot;44100\\\&quot; mimeType=\\\&quot;video/mp4\\\&quot; startWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026amp;srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026amp;srcAg=CHROME\\u0026amp;ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026amp;type=2\\u0026amp;sig=MyZn0feEv34\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=834622982720\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\&quot;1344-2419\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\&quot;0-1343\\\&quot;/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003CRepresentation id=\\\&quot;4\\\&quot; bandwidth=\\\&quot;2653949\\\&quot; width=\\\&quot;1280\\\&quot; height=\\\&quot;720\\\&quot; quality=\\\&quot;hd\\\&quot; frameRate=\\\&quot;30\\\&quot; codecs=\\\&quot;avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2\\\&quot; audioSamplingRate=\\\&quot;44100\\\&quot; mimeType=\\\&quot;video/mp4\\\&quot; startWithSAP=\\\&quot;1\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CBaseURL\\u003Ehttps://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026amp;srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026amp;srcAg=CHROME\\u0026amp;ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026amp;type=3\\u0026amp;sig=F8Z1zwkFbnY\\u0026amp;ct=4\\u0026amp;urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026amp;clientType=0\\u0026amp;id=834622982720\\u003C/BaseURL\\u003E\\u003CSegmentBase indexRange=\\\&quot;1343-2418\\\&quot;\\u003E\\u003CInitialization range=\\\&quot;0-1342\\\&quot;/\\u003E\\u003C/SegmentBase\\u003E\\u003C/Representation\\u003E\\u003C/AdaptationSet\\u003E\\u003C/Period\\u003E\\u003C/MPD\\u003E\&quot;,\&quot;metadataUrl\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/?expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=45.136.22.4\\u0026type=1\\u0026sig=sZsahX1_3M4\\u0026ct=6\\u0026urls=185.226.53.5\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;hlsManifestUrl\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd379.mycdn.me/video.m3u8?cmd=videoPlayerCdn\\u0026expires=1605039025583\\u0026srcIp=41.40.174.135\\u0026srcAg=CHROME\\u0026ms=185.226.52.74\\u0026type=4\\u0026sig=wobTwftQXMY\\u0026ct=8\\u0026urls=45.136.21.8\\u0026clientType=0\\u0026id=834622982720\&quot;,\&quot;failoverHosts\&quot;:[\&quot;vd296.mycdn.me\&quot;],\&quot;autoplay\&quot;:{\&quot;autoplayEnabled\&quot;:true,\&quot;timeFromEnabled\&quot;:true,\&quot;noRec\&quot;:false,\&quot;fullScreenExit\&quot;:false,\&quot;vitrinaSection\&quot;:\&quot;recommended_movie\&quot;},\&quot;security\&quot;:{\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;https://vd196.mycdn.me/usr_login\&quot;,\&quot;cookie\&quot;:\&quot;vdsig\&quot;},\&quot;p2pInfo\&quot;:{\&quot;isPeerEnabled\&quot;:false,\&quot;ubsc\&quot;:0,\&quot;pbsc\&quot;:0,\&quot;mptpc\&quot;:0,\&quot;pctmt\&quot;:0,\&quot;pbesc\&quot;:0,\&quot;prrt\&quot;:0,\&quot;srt\&quot;:0,\&quot;swrt\&quot;:0,\&quot;dctt\&quot;:0},\&quot;stunServers\&quot;:[{\&quot;urls\&quot;:[\&quot;stun:videostun.mycdn.me\&quot;]}]}&quot;,&quot;saveLastPlayingTimeFrom&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;castId&quot;:&quot;559D7832&quot;,&quot;locale&quot;:&quot;en&quot;,&quot;noChatLikes&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;noChannel&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;webmSec&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;enabledLocalStorage&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;minCacheTime&quot;:&quot;120&quot;,&quot;maxCachePartOfDurationMQ&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;checkMQ&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;noTrailer&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;recSlot&quot;:&quot;7178&quot;,&quot;noLikeButton&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;maxCachePartOfDuration&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;isAnonym&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;jidx&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;hideWatermark&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;isEmbed&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;noOkliveBanner&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;minCacheTimeMQ&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;ldChunk&quot;:&quot;2000&quot;,&quot;showChat&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;ldBuffer&quot;:&quot;6000&quot;,&quot;feedAdLogic&quot;:&quot;15,3,3,14400&quot;,&quot;location&quot;:&quot;AnonymVideoEmbed/anonymVideoEmbed/anonym&quot;,&quot;hideExpand&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;adLogic&quot;:&quot;15,0,3,14400&quot;,&quot;checkAutoplayBrowsers&quot;:&quot;safari,chrome,opera,yandex,firefox&quot;},&quot;liveRertyTimeout&quot;:5000,&quot;poster&quot;:&quot;https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=AEF0PjOBfKSCKs0AX-NHBglGBtoSnlj-w7r7-4MFAFw9g4biXbYyD2f2E83LOe0CGcT12ru7KHrHmBnSbxBCDBLP\u0026fn=external_8&quot;,&quot;isExternalPlayer&quot;:false,&quot;isIframePlayer&quot;:false,&quot;isHtml5Player&quot;:true,&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;1604952625588&quot;,&quot;stubEnabled&quot;:false,&quot;verifyInline&quot;:false,&quot;webrtcBrokenH264&quot;:false}" data-player-container-id="embedVideoC" data-player-element-id="embedVideoE" data-visible-part="1" data-use-events-for-showing="true" class="vid-card_cnt h-mod"><div class="vid-card_cnt_w" data-l="t,play" id="embedVideoC"><div class="vid_play"><svg class="svg-ic svg-ico_media_play_16 svg-ic48 vid_play-ic" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M5 4.072a.7.7 0 0 1 1.122-.559l5.204 3.928a.699.699 0 0 1 0 1.118l-5.204 3.928A.7.7 0 0 1 5 11.928V4.072z" fill-rule="evenodd" class="svg-fill"></path>
</svg></div><img src="https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=AEF0PjOBfKSCKs0AX-NHBglGBtoSnlj-w7r7-4MFAFw9g4biXbYyD2f2E83LOe0CGcT12ru7KHrHmBnSbxBCDBLP&amp;fn=external_8" class="vid-card_img" style=""><div class="vid-card_duration-w"><div class="vid-card_duration">21:34</div></div><div class="vid-card_n_w"><span class="vid-card_n">ikyn-133ar</span></div></div></div>
```

I am trying to check if *data-module* exists or not:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#Playerholder > iframe"))) 
x = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#embedVideoC > div'))
```

Comment: Which element? How did you try?

Comment: I tried ``WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#Playerholder > iframe")))``

``x=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#embedVideoC > div')))``

I managed to select the element but I don't know how to check for the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test presence of attribute, try

```
if x.get_attribute('data-module'):
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-module]')
```

Comment: I want to perform an If/else action where if it exists it prints true and if it doesn't exist it prints false

Comment: I think if it doesn't exist this line will raise this exception NoSuchElementException, you can use a try-except block to handle this specific exception, and print true inside the try block and false inside the except block.